# Get button sender ImageBrush.ImageSource from XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

First of all I have multiple buttons that Send me to another page and I want that on second page to show `ImageBrush` of this Button. Fields like `x:Name`, `Tag` and `Content` are already busy so I can't use them. My buttons are like this:

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="but01" Click="Button2_Click" Tag="this tag is bussy" Content="First Button" >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="brush1" ImageSource="/Assets/Logos/1.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this is what I've tried
    var brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush = (ImageBrush)((sender as Button).Background);
    string mynew = brush.ImageSource.ToString();
    NavigationService.Navigate(
        new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?path=" +
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode((sender as Button).Tag.ToString())+ "&source="+ mynew,
                UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Where `mynew = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`
and I want it to be: `/Assets/Logos/1.png`

Any ideas? Maybe there is other fields where I can store this path except `Tag`, `Name` and `Content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **BitmapImage** instead of **ImageSource**.

You can get the image path like this:

```
var brush = but01.Background as ImageBrush;
BitmapImage source = brush.ImageSource as BitmapImage;
Uri uri = source.UriSource;
string uriStr = uri.OriginalString;
```

the field **uriStr** is the value you want !